# error in xml-rpc search method from php client

Tags: php, python, web-services, xml-rpc

I want to get data from a WS using xml-rpc.
The connection is successful, but when I set the arguments in a name_search method, I have a this exception:

```
error : Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/openerp/odoo/odoo/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 82, in xmlrpc_return
    result = openerp.netsvc.dispatch_rpc(service, method, params)
File "/home/openerp/odoo/odoo/openerp/netsvc.py", line 296, in dispatch_rpc
    result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
File "/home/openerp/odoo/odoo/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 626, in dispatch
    res = fn(db, uid, *params) File "/home/openerp/odoo/odoo/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 132, in wrapper
    return f(, dbname, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/openerp/odoo/odoo/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 199, in 
    res = ._cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)
File "/home/openerp/odoo/odoo/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 187, in _cr
    return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)
File "/home/openerp/odoo/esigpen/prison_person/prison_person.py", line 287, in name_search
    ('identificador', 'ilike', name)] + args
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "NoneType") to list
```

I'm using phpxmlrpc-2.2.2 library for the connection and I send the arguments through $val. In this case I'm sending the name cris.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<?php

require_once('phpxmlrpc-2.2.2/lib/xmlrpc.inc');
require_once('phpxmlrpc-2.2.2/lib/xmlrpcs.inc');
$GLOBALS['xmlrpc_internalencoding']='UTF-8';

$dbname = '*****';
$user = '****';
$password = '****';

$server_url = 'http://23.000.160.000:8069'; 
$connexion = new xmlrpc_client($server_url . "/xmlrpc/common");
$connexion->setSSLVerifyPeer(0);

$c_msg = new xmlrpcmsg('login');
$c_msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($dbname, "string"));
$c_msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($user, "string"));
$c_msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($password, "string"));
$c_response = $connexion->send($c_msg);

if ($c_response->errno != 0){
    echo  '<p>error : ' . $c_response->faultString() . '</p>';
}
else{

    $uid = $c_response->value()->scalarval();

  $val = array ( 
        new xmlrpcval(
            array(new xmlrpcval('cris', "string"), 

                  ),"array"             
            ),
        );


    $client = new xmlrpc_client($server_url . "/xmlrpc/object");
    $client->setSSLVerifyPeer(0);

    $msg = new xmlrpcmsg(); 
    $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($dbname, "string")); 
    $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($uid, "int")); 
    $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($password, "string")); 
    $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval("prison.person", "string")); 
    $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval("name_search", "string"));     
    $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($val, "struct")); 


    $response = $client->send($msg);    
    if ($response->errno != 0){
    echo  '<p>error : ' . $response->faultString() . '</p>';
      }
    $result = $response->value();
    $ids = $result->scalarval();



}
?>
```

This is the Python code where are the methods to search:

https://gist.github.com/name1984/a7e78af7dba738449bc0

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The error:

```
File "/home/openerp/odoo/esigpen/prison_person/prison_person.py", line 287, in name_search
    ('identificador', 'ilike', name)] + args
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "NoneType") to list
```

Seems to be caused by this line:
https://gist.github.com/name1984/a7e78af7dba738449bc0#file-gistfile1-py-L15

`name_search` is being passed `args=None`. You could remove the `+ args` and do this:

```
if args is not None:
    domain += args
```